# Find out which iOS App store an app has been downloaded from

Tags: ios, internationalization, app-store

I am working on an iOS app which has country-specific content and I am planning to have one app with localized meta-data and content.

I know it is possible to programmatically find out the phone's locale to render content accordingly; but:

Is it possible to find out which App Store (US, UK, etc.) the app came from? or... alternatively which country is the current App store account associated with?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you figure out any solution for this ?